# CSS overriding bootstrap table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here're my selectors:

```
table.table.table-striped.vitalStatisticsTable th,
table.table.table-striped.vitalStatisticsTable td {
  line-height: 1;
  padding: .4rem; 
  background-color: red;
}
```

Here's my markup:

```
<table class="table table-striped vitalStatisticsTable">
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Education</th>
    <td>Post Graduate</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th scope="row">Vices</th>
    <td>Drinks socially</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Race</th>
    <td>White</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Pets</th>
    <td>George the turtle</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My rules are not applied, but I'm not really sure what i'm doing wrong.  I thought I had to increase specificity, and as I understand it, I am being more specific than bootstrap, but maybe i'm missing something.  Can someone help a css n00b out?

Comment: this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Well.  Actually this does work.  I had an extra "}" in my CSS file.  I'm ashamed and relieved all at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:
table.vitalStatisticsTable th,
table.vitalStatisticsTable td
This will work. All class not need to mention in selector.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work either.  Thanks for the suggestion though.